# How to do multiple let in for loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can I assign 2 let in for loop? I tried this but gives me warning `k[ts] ')' expected.`:

```
for(let key in app.date let key2 in app.date2) {
        data_series.push({
            "year": app.date[key]._id,
            "italy": app.date[key].count,
            "germany": app.date2[key2].count2,
        });
    }
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Can you provide what `app` looks like as a data structure?

Comment: You can only use 1 iterating condition in your for loop, you have 2. You cannot do both `let key in app.date` and  `let key2 in app.date2`

Comment: if ``app.date`` and ``app.date2`` have the same number of elements, use a good old ``for (let i = 0; i < arr; i++)`` loop and use the ``i`` like so ```app.date[i]``` and ```app.date2[i]```. Otherwise just use two different loops.

Comment: objects do not have guaranteed key order, so if your data looks like `var app = {date: { ... }, date2: { ... } }` there is no way to properly associate the values of `date` and `date2` unless they happen to have the same keys (which does not appear to be the case from your code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that both objects have the same number of keys, in order to iterate over both at once, you'd have to first construct an object of some sort that contains key pairs. But, from your code, it looks like you're interested only in the *value* at that key, not the key itself - if what you want is clear, short code, you might use an array method instead: iterate over the `Object.values` of `app.date`, and use the index to access the appropriate value inside `date2`:

```
const date2Values = Object.values(app.date2);
Object.values(app.date).forEach(({ _id, count }, i) => {
  data_series.push({
    year: _id,
    italy: count,
    germany: date2Values[i].count2
  });
});
```

If you *had* to use `for`, then construct an object of key pairs beforehand, and iterate with `for..of`:

```
const date2Keys = Object.keys(app.date2);
const allKeys = Object.keys(app.date)
  .map((key, i) => ({ key, key2: date2Keys[i] }));
for (const { key, key2 } of allKeys) {
  // etc
}
```

or, it might be clearer with a *plain* for loop instead:

```
const dateKeys = Object.keys(app.date);
const date2Keys = Object.keys(app.date2);
for (let i = 0, { length } + Object.keys(app.date); i < length; i++) {
  const key = dateKeys[i];
  const key2 = date2Keys[i];
  // etc
}
```

But the `Object.values` version is probably preferable, since it's more abstract, functional, and doesn't require manual iteration.

Also, if `data_series` is an empty array beforehand, it would be more appropriate to use `.map` than to use `forEach` and `push`:

```
const date2Values = Object.values(app.date2);
const data_series = Object.values(app.date).map(({ _id, count }, i) => ({
  year: _id,
  italy: count,
  germany: date2Values[i].count2
});
```

If at all possible, I'd recommend changing your data structure so that each item of `date` and `date2` is clearly associated with the other, such as an array, rather than depending on each object happening to have the same ordered property names. Although property order *is* guaranteed in modern browsers, it's not a good thing for code to depend on.

Comment: Does it implies that ```app.date``` and ```app.date2``` should have the same number of elements?

Comment: Don't forget that objects do not have guaranteed key order - see my comment above

Comment: great! thanks for many options, changing data structure worked for me